# Peut-on dire « une auteure »?

Tags: usage, genre, noms, genre-biologique

Manifestement, ni le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/auteure) ni l'[Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/auteure) n'acceptent le terme, et [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=auteure) n'est pas particulièrement enthousiaste non plus.

Cependant, il semblerait que l'usage d'*une auteure* soit [commun au Québec](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/auteure) et que, d'une manière générale, cet usage [augmente depuis 1980](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=auteure&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3).

Quelle tendance suivre?

Comment: On peut. Mais c'est moche ! ;-)

Comment: Pas sans rapport. http://correcteurs.blog.lemonde.fr/2011/11/04/areur-areure-areuse/ note un article où _rapporteur_, _rapporteure_ et _rapporteuse_ sont utilisés pour désigner la même personne.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dans le corpus de Google Ngrams, on voit qu'“une auteure” décolle très vite à partir de 1980 et a largement dépassé “une auteur”, que l'on rencontrait de temps en temps. “Une autrice”, admis autrefois, est maintenant tombé en désuétude. “Une auteuse” et “une autoresse” n'ont jamais vraiment trouvé preneur.

[image: une auteure,une auteur,une autrice,une auteuse]

Par contre, ils sont tous trois très peu employés comparés à “un auteur”. Le diagramme suivant compare la fréquence relative des féminins d'*auteur* avec celui, incontesté, de *conducteur*.
[image: une auteure/un auteur,une autrice/un auteur,une auteuse/un auteur,une conductrice/un conducteur]

Pendant un temps, en gros au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle, on utilisait l'expression “une femme auteur”. Cette formule a été éclipsée par l'envolée d'“une auteure” autour de 1980. . Christine Planté analyse cette expression dans [“Elle n'eut d'ailleurs rien de la femme auteur”](https://books.google.fr/books?id=agjT-OugFccC&pg=PA36&dq=%22femme+auteur%22&hl=en) (dans *George Sand lue à l'étranger : recherches nouvelles 3, Actes du Colloque d'Amsterdam, 1995*).

[image: femme auteur/auteur, auteure/auteur]

Si l'on essaie de classer par pays (attention, ces décomptes ne sont pas du tout fiables) :

- Il y a environ 4 500 000 occurrences de `"un auteur"` sur les sites `.fr`, environ 50 000 de `"une auteur"` et à peu près autant de `"une auteure"`.
- Sur les sites `.be`, on trouve environ 200 000 `"un auteur"`, 2500 `"une auteur"`, et 4000 `"une auteure"`.
- Sur les sites `.ca`, on trouve environ 150 000 `"un auteur"`, 8000 `"une auteur"`, et 20 000 `"une auteure"`.

Je ne sais pas à quels point ces approximations sont fiables (si quelqu'un a un meilleur corpus à suggérer, je suis preneur), mais il semblerait quand même que “une auteure” est plus employé au Québec qu'ailleurs, et est très minoritaire ailleurs. Quant à “une autrice”, il est marginal sur le web.

L'histoire du féminin d'*auteur*, ainsi que [celui d'*écrivain*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89crivain#F.C3.A9minisation), a passionné de nombreux historiens de la langue, sociologues et féministes. Aurore Evain a notamment écrit une savante (bien que basée sur un corpus restreint) [Histoire d'*autrice*, de l'époque latine de nos jours](http://www.siefar.org/docsiefar/file/Histoire%20d'autrice%20-%20A_%20Evain.pdf) [sic], dans laquelle les formes *auteuse* et *auteure* sont aussi évoquées. Elle décrit les usages ainsi :

> En 1998, la nouvelle commission mise en place par Lionel Jospin « ose » le féminin  auteure, selon un principe de précaution qui avait déjà guidé le choix des Québecois en la matière, et malgré les autres usages en cours dans la francophonie, la Suisse et l’Afrique francophone employant quant à eux le féminin *autrice*.

En résumé, le choix le plus neutre politiquement reste encore *un auteur* en France, en Belgique et en Suisse, alors qu'*une auteure* passera bien au Québec, et *une autrice* peut-être en Afrique.

Comment: il me semble que le terme autrice est demandé par les groupes féministes ce dernier étant le terme originale pour désigner un auteur au féminin.

Comment: Pour le corpus, il me semble clair que *«un auteur»* tiendra le haut du pavé et de loin. Toute référence générale plutôt que particulière, à moins qu’elle ne s’applique spécifiquement aux femmes auteur(e)s/autrices, sera masculine par défaut. Tout auteur homme sera désigné de cette manière aussi. Ne reste que les femmes auteur(e)s/autrices pour faire le contepoids des trois groupes de l’autre côté de la balance (ceux des auteurs généraux, ceux des hommes auteurs et ceux des femmes désignées *«un auteur»* selon le choix de l’écrivain).

Comment: @Montéedelait C'est vrai que « un auteur » inclut des utilisations neutres, mais comparé à d'autres paires comme conducteur/conductrice par exemple, auteur est nettement moins féminisé. J'ai remplacé le diagramme par un autre qui est plus adapté.

Comment: @Gilles Cet exemple est plus convaincant. Merci de vous y être penché et de l’avoir inclus. +1

Comment: [Un autre graphique](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=femme+auteur%2Cfemme+auteure%2Cfemme+autrice%2Cune+auteur%2Cune+auteure&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfemme%20auteur%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfemme%20auteur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFemme%20auteur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfemme%20auteure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20auteur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cune%20auteure%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bune%20auteure%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUne%20auteure%3B%2Cc0), que je trouve curieux, mais qui est peut-être aisément explicable.

Comment: @Montéedelait Effectivement, il semble que “femme auteur” était l'expression consacrée dans les cercles littéraires au 19e siècle.

Comment: Finalement, le principal argument pour écrire *un auteur* pour une femme, c'est que ça évite quand même toute une foule de question ^^

Answer (score 4):

J'ai cru comprendre que c'est un usage toléré (peut-être même courant ?) au Québec.

Mais l'Académie Française considère cet usage comme incorrect.
http://www.academie-francaise.fr/langue/questions.html#feminisation

Comment: Auteure est utilisé par ceux qui veulent flatter le côté féministe, mais je persiste à trouver le mot malsonnant et peu esthétique. Autrice sonne bizarre aussi (collision avec autiste ?). Pas facile de trouver une bonne alternative !

Comment: L'Académie a un bon argument en rappelant que ce devrait être à la rigueur _auteuse_ ou _autrice_, mais certainement pas _auteure_.

Answer (score 3):

À mon avis oui, mais écrivaine me semble plus courant (édit: [Google n'est pas d'accord](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=auteure%2C%C3%A9crivaine&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=7&smoothing=3)).  Voir aussi la section féminisation de [l'article de wikipédia sur écrivain](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%A9crivain) qui contient un petit historique (« écrivaine » aurait été utilisé dès le XIVème et « autrice » aurait été utilisé dès le XVIème).

Comment: Surtout, *écrivain* n'est pas synonyme d'*auteur*. On dit “quel est l'auteur de ce rapport ?” mais pas “quel est l'écrivain de ce rapport ?”…

Answer (score 2):

> [...] il semblerait que l'usage d'*une auteure* soit commun au Québec
>   [...]

Au **Québec**<sup>1</sup>, l'[usage](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3943) d'[*auteure*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1905) est établi et ce choix de féminin obtenu par l'ajout du *e* au nom masculin en [-eur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-eur) avait fait l'objet d'une proposition qui a été retenue ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3336)). Le souci de protéger le patrimoine linguistique construit et l'analyse de la meilleure manière de suffixer les noms de métiers et de professions au féminin sont des considérations pertinentes et elles sont validées ; dans certains cas il y a concurrence entre différentes formations et on verra à l'usage, et ce qui se passe ailleurs dans la francophonie est aussi bien intéressant. Par ailleurs, au-delà des considérations purement lexicales « l’emploi des appellations au féminin coordonnées aux appellations au masculin vise avant tout à offrir une égale représentation des hommes et des femmes dans les textes » ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4015#question1)) ; en effet on peut faire le choix d'une [*représentation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/repr%C3%A9sentation) clairement égale dans un texte. Plus particulièrement, l'emploi d'appellations au féminin est « [recommandé](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31963) » pour désigner des femmes par l'OQLF mais il n'est pas considéré comme « obligatoire » ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4015#question2)) et les règles grammaticales n'ont pas changé ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4015#question4)) ; [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17905) on a aussi parlé du choix de ceux ou celles que l'on désigne et je crois que c'est bien important de le respecter.

Plus généralement, la fonction générique du masculin peut certainement être remise en question dans certains cas (GDT) : « face à une appellation de personne au masculin, la lectrice ou le lecteur doit faire un effort de décodage supplémentaire pour savoir s'il s'agit d'un masculin générique, censé désigner aussi bien les femmes que les hommes, ou d'un masculin à valeur spécifique, qui ne désigne que les hommes » (GDT, [*masculin générique*](http://www.gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26532333)). Ce genre de réflexion peut s'appliquer au cas qui nous occupe. On oublie aussi trop souvent dans ce genre de question comment l'appellation peut s'insérer dans un texte et ce qu'elle y déterminera, comme le pronom etc. possiblement selon la [formulation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47128096#47128096) des phrases ; il y a différents [défis](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect9&info0=9) de rédaction dans le domaine de féminisation. Quoiqu'il en soit l'usage d'*une auteure* au Québec me semble bien plus que *commun* et en ce qui me concerne je le qualifierais plutôt de *systématique* (chez moi du moins) et je ne connaissais avant de m'y attarder ici aucun autre usage de ce mot (*autrice*, *auteuse*, le masculin générique, le déterminant féminin avec le mot auteur à valeur épicène etc.).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> J'ai cependant noté la présence de l'[*auteure*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/auteur/6555?q=auteure#6532) au *Larousse en ligne*.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

À la lecture des réponses, je suis un peu étonné que personne ne s'intéresse à la version "une auteur", qui féminise simplement la fonction sans torturer le mot. Cela s'applique d'ailleurs à de nombeux autres noms (professeur, etc.). La réticence de l'Académie à considérer ces mots comme épicènes n'est pas explicite et comme correcteur j'ai pu constater que c'est un compromis qui a la faveur de nombreuses personnes

Answer (score 1):

Pourquoi pas utiliser la forme autrice (comme pour acteur→actrice) ?

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/autrice#Notes

https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2019/02/28/autrice-le-feminin-qui-genait-tant-lacademie-francaise-est-tout-sauf-un-neologisme_a_23680379/

https://www.franceculture.fr/litterature/autrice-la-tres-vielle-histoire-dun-mot-controverse

Answer (score -6):

En France, on ne doit dire ni "écrivaine", ni "auteure". Ce ne sont que des ajouts à l'orientation politique qui ne représentent rien au final. Seule l'Académie française est garante des règles de la langue (et non les féministes). Ainsi, les réponses ne se trouvent pas sur Wikipédia.

Dans tous les cas il faut dire "un écrivain" et "un auteur". Il ne s'agit pas réellement du masculin mais du masculin utilisé de façon neutre.

- Madame le ministre est l'auteur de ce rapport.
- Agata Christie est un formidable écrivain.

https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/%C3%A9crivain?page=1
https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/auteur?page=1

Comment: En France, il n'existe aucune forme de *devoir* en termes de vocabulaire. Un mot arrive, il est compris par le public ou non. Il est apprécié et entre dans l'usage ou oublié. L'AF ne fait *rien d'autre* que constater ces faits. Elle n'est en aucun cas garante de quoi que ce soit.

Comment: Larousse en ligne a [_auteure_](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/auteur/6555?q=auteure#6532) et [_écrivaine_](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%c3%a9crivain_n/27747?q=%c3%a9crivain#27600) et dans ce dernier cas on dit qu'on trouve aussi parfois avec le déterminant au féminin (_une_).

Comment: https://www.franceculture.fr/litterature/autrice-la-tres-vielle-histoire-dun-mot-controverse

Comment: Un académicien propose une vision bien plus nuancée [ici](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-nest-pas-comme-le-rugby-un-combat), y établissant que son simple manque d'habitude et d'exposition aux versions féminines justifie son peu de goût pour celles-ci. Il admet candidement que son opinion pourrait très bien n'être que temporaire, si l'usage s'impose et y habitue son oreille.