# Comment appelle-t-on une femme qui gagne sa vie de l'écriture ?

Tags: genre, professions

Une femme qui gagne sa vie en écrivant est une ?

Dans un bouquin, j'ai vu le mot "écrivaine", mais mon livre de grammaire dit que le bon terme est "femme écrivain".

Comment: le CNRTL n'a pas encore admit les mots *écrivaine* et *auteure*

Comment: Le CNRTL n'admet rien et n'a rien à admettre puisque ce n'est pas un dictionnaire ;). Le TFLi n'a par contre en effet pas d'entrée pour *auteure* et *écrivaine*.

Comment: @Evpok, Le TLFi a une note sur le sujet à l’entrée [écrivain](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ecrivain).

Comment: @Unfrancophone Qu'est ce que le TLFi puisque votre lien pointe vers le site du CNRTL (Je ne connais pas la différence)

Comment: @Clippy, le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/dictionnaires/modernes/) est un des dictionnaires mis à disposition par le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depuis une quarantaine d'années les noms de métiers se féminisent et malgré [la condamnation de l'emploi de certains mots par l'Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/feminisation-des-noms-de-metiers-fonctions-grades-et-titres) « écrivaine » et « auteure » sont de plus en plus répandus en France.

Un ngram sur les mots ["auteure" et "écrivaine"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=auteure,%20%C3%A9crivaine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,auteure;,c0;.t1;,%C3%A9crivaine;,c0).

Voir sur fr.stackexchange [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/448/358) sur auteure.

Dans la presse récente des exemples avec « écrivaine » :
- [*Le Monde*](http://www.lemonde.fr/disparitions/article/2013/11/09/mort-de-l-ecrivaine-sibylle-lacan_3511291_3382.html)
- [*Libération*](http://www.liberation.fr/culture/2013/11/17/l-ecrivaine-doris-lessing-est-morte_947577)

Comment: Dit autrement, on doit dire "Madame est (un) (grand) auteur" mais certains font l'erreur volontairement pour faire preuve de féminisme

Answer (score 3):

La féminisation des noms est un sujet de débats de nos jours. Traditionnellement, on emploie « un écrivain » quel que soit le sexe de l’écrivain, d’autres diront « une écrivain » (~« une femme écrivain » me semble douteux) , d’autres préconisent « une écrivaine ».

Et ne parlons pas du féminin d’« auteur ».

Comment: Et pourquoi pas? *Auteure* est d'un usage très courant au Québec.

Comment: @Circeus et il s'utilise de plus en plus en France. Il est vrai qu'*écrit-vaine* sonne douloureusement aux oreilles, mais ce n'est peut-être qu'un manque d'habitude

Comment: @Circeus Parce qu’« auteure » est horrible. Je suis évidemment pour la féminisation, mais pitié choisissons bien les termes. « Autoresse » a ma préférence. Comme « [doctoresse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/doctoresse) ».

Comment: Pardon Edouard, mais j'ai l'exact sentiment inverse... *une auteure* sonne très bien à mes oreilles. Difficile à expliquer, cela dit.

Answer (score 2):

J'ai entendu récemment une interview d'une telle femme à qui le journaliste posait cette question.

Sa réponse a été: *Je suis une romancière*.

Comment: Avec romancière le problème est contourné ! Cependant, une romancière écrit des romans, ce qui est un type de livre particulier. Écrivain, auteur, c'est plus général.

Answer (score 1):

According to the book Essential French Grammar (p. 44)

*Traditionally, most professions in France have not had feminine forms but recent
changes in social attitudes have led to new feminine forms being created. These forms are gradually becoming accepted, despite some disagreement among linguists.*

Some examples given

> une **écrivaine** is in common use
>
> la ministre, as an alternative to Madame le Ministre
>
> la juge, as an alternative to Madame le Juge
>
> For a woman doctor, une femme médecin or un médecin is used.
>
> un auteur (author); une auteure is used in Quebec only

According to the authors, *in Quebec, by contrast with France, the use of feminine titles is very widespread, accepted and often compulsory. There are uses that appear only rarely in France, such as*

> la docteure (woman doctor), even though the feminine of docteur,
>   doctoresse, already exists,
>
> la médecin,
>
> la gouverneure (woman governor),
>
> la ministre (female minister),
>
> la première ministre (woman prime minister),
>
> la mairesse (or la maire) (mayoress), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Il existe les recommandations officielles et les usages militants qui peuvent passer pour une figure de style. En l’occurrence, si pour des raisons idéologiques ou simplement pour la cohérence tu souhaite féminiser des mots, n’hésite pas à le faire.

C’est précisément l’attitude que j’adopte pour tous les mots à l’exception d’*écrivaine* parce-que ce dernier sonne mal :)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>…*Brève de comptoir :*</sup>

« ***Si*** écrivain était vraiment neutre, on penserait :

> **un écrivain** et **une écrivain** *tels* Balzac et Colette …

… impensable décès du patriarcat qui rendrait les adjectifs *neutres* et le français trop facile à apprendre… Oui Monsieur ! »