# « Masculinisation » des noms

Tags: genre, genre-biologique

Je sais qu'une classe de noms —notamment des noms de profession— désigne aussi bien un homme qu'une femme bien que ces noms soient masculins (au moins pour l'académie française et les grammairiens).

> un censeur, un médecin, un écrivain, un maire, un président, un
>   témoin, un professeur.

Je sais qu'il y a aussi un mouvement pour la féminisation de ces noms :

> une écrivaine, une maire, une professeure, etc.

Voir la discussion ici

[Comment appelle-t-on une femme qui gagne sa vie de l'écriture ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9110/comment-appelle-t-on-une-femme-qui-gagne-sa-vie-de-l%C3%A9criture)

Or, il existe également une autre classe de noms qui désigne aussi bien des hommes et des femmes bien que ces noms soient féminins.

> Une idole, une star, une recrue, une canaille, une vedette, une
>   sentinelle, une personne.

Je me demande donc s'il y a aussi un mouvement homologue pour la "masculinisation" de tels noms. Par exemple

> Un personne, un idole, un recru(e), un sentinelle, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

il n'est pas franchement politiquement correct de masculiniser en ces temps de démagogie.

Quoi qu'il en soit, nos langues viennent de l'indo-européen, qui ne connaissait pas le masculin ni le féminin, mais l'animé et l'inanimé, le premier se divisant tardivement en masculin et féminin. D'où des hésitations non rares : nauta (le marin) ou collega (le collègue) en latin sont du masculin car désignant des hommes mais la terminaison est féminine ; das Weib (la femme) est … du neutre en allemand ; les Néerlandais ont résolu partiellement la question en répartissant les substantifs en « genre commun » et neutre.

Pour le français, un grand nombre de noms sont d'apparence et de genre grammatical *éventuellement* masculin, mais sont d'origine ni l'un ni l'autre quant au sens, e.g. ministre ; la démagogie ambiante d'une minorité agissante face à la majorité silencieuse fait féminiser un certain nombre de noms avec des énormités occasionnelles et du bon sens quand il subsiste.

De toute façon, idole par exemple est une métaphore, donc n'a pas à changer de genre, ça tombe bien parce qu'il est du neutre en latin (idolum) et en grec (εἴδωλον). Pour sentinelle, c'était du féminin déjà en italien. Et ainsi de suite, il n'y a pas corrélation systématique entre le genre grammatical et celui du sens. La féminisation des noms en particulier de métier est donc partiellement une fumisterie, l'absence de masculinisation symétrique une malhonnêteté intellectuelle.

Pas rigolo tout ça (encore que cela pourrait l'être : comment appeler une personne ministre qui se trouverait être transgenre, hmm ?). En tout cas apprenez vos genres par cœur, c'est le seul moyen de ne pas attirer de sourires moqueurs ou compatissants en cas d'erreur.

Answer (score 4):

Réponse courte: non, pas du tout. Je n'imagine pas un locuteur natif dire « un personne », « un idole », etc. Cela sonnerait comme une faute.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Pourquoi pas ? Je le trouve logique quand même. Une écrivaine, une professeure mais une personne, une idole toujours pour les femmes et les hommes ? Pas de parité ☺!

Comment: Une explication qui n'engage que moi: la tendance à la féminisation des noms de fonction ou métiers est due à une volonté de "rééquilibrer" la langue française, vue comme privilégiant le masculin (et donc les hommes). Donc, ce mouvement ne va pas dans les deux sens... A tort ou à raison ? Le débat est ouvert...

Comment: Merci pour le commentaire bien précis. Cependant c'est bizarre quand même (du moins pour un non natif comme moi). Une sentinelle désigne aussi bien des hommes que des femmes. Un médecin désigne aussi bien des hommes que des femmes. Des genres grammaticaux. Et voici je viens de résoudre le grand problème:-)!

Comment: ... et il y a pire: une *sage-femme* peut être un homme !

Comment: C'est fou, non ? Et pourquoi pas un sage-homme ? Question rhétorique:-)!

Comment: C'est mieux d'utiliser **maïeuticien(ne)** :-)!

Comment: En fait le "femme" dans sage-femme fait référence à la femme qui donne naissance et non pas au médecin, c'est pour ça qu'un homme peut être sage-femme :)

Comment: @TimLepage  Comment un homme peut donner naissance ? On ne parle de l'obstétricien ? Je n'arrive pas à comprendre.

Comment: Non non l'homme ne donne pas naissance ! Je dis juste que le "femme" de "sage-femme" fait référence a la femme qui accouche c'est pour ça qu'un sage-femme désigne indifféremment un homme ou une femme.

Comment: "Sage" est à comprendre dans le sens ancien de "savant", donc *sage-femme* voulait dire étymologiquement "qui connait les femmes". Le terme est resté féminin parce que c'était une profession  traditionnellement réservée aux femmes.

Comment: @Greg – cela est très contesté, d'ailleurs historiquement et même préhistoriquement, seules les femmes s'occupaient d'accouchement, les hommes partant couiner dans leur coin en laissant le Mystère de la Naissance auquel ils n'entendaient rien se dérouler loin d'eux, entre femmes (d'autant que la parturiente avait en plus une chance d'y laisser sa peau et le bébé idem …)