# Est-ce une hérésie de dire « Madame LA ministre » ?

Tags: usage, accord, genre, genre-biologique, professions

J'ai appris à l'école que l'on devait dire "Madame LE ministre" car ministre est une fonction et non un métier, c'est donc un mot neutre et en français le masculin à valeur de neutre fait office de neutre.

Cependant du coup je ne vois pas pourquoi on ne pourrait pas dire "LA médecin", à part que ça écorche les oreilles. À moins que médecin ne soit pas un métier mais une fonction ce qui donnerait la situation cocasse de dire  "LE médecin" (fonction) et "LA médecin généraliste" (métier)
Ou alors je n'ai rien compris ? Y a-t'il un moyen de s'y retrouver à coup sûr ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ministre et médecin sont des mots masculins, donc à mon avis (de puriste), c'est toujours "le". Peu importe que la personne soit un homme ou une femme [d'ailleurs, un homme est UNE personne... ce n'est pas gênant].

Si on veut vraiment préciser le sexe de la personne, on peut dire : "une femme médecin".

Comment: « Ministre et médecin sont des mots masculins » — oui, évidemment, si ce sont des noms masculins, on dit « le ». La question est pourquoi ce seraient des noms masculins et pas épicènes.

Comment: @Gilles C'est précisément ce que je conteste.

Comment: La question est plus sociale que linguistique. Médecin et ministre n'ont pas de forme féminines (pour des raisons qui découlent de pratiques sociales -discriminatoires ici). Or d'autres fonctions longtemps exercées majoritairement par des femmes telles qu'infirmière, ont une forme masculine (infirmier). La question est donc plus de voir comment les gens utilisent la langue pour la modifier et donc quelle forme entre dans le langage.

Answer (score 15):

Ce n'est plus une hérésie, les journalistes le font depuis très longtemps et tous les gouvernements francophones l'autorisent ou l'imposent depuis plus ou moins de temps.

C'est même la forme la plus courante à l'écrit depuis 1998 :

[image]

En France, c'est Yvette Roudy qui a initié ce changement en exigeant dès 1983 qu'on l'appelle *madame la ministre*.

Le 16 mars 1986, une [circulaire du journal officiel de la République française](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jo_pdf.do?id=JORFTEXT000000866501) recommande la féminisation des titres, et donc de pouvoir dire *une ministre* et *une médecin* et annonce la formation d'une commission chargée de fournir un rapport sur le sujet.

La circulaire de 1986 ayant peu été suivie d'effets, elle a été reprise le [6 mars 1998](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000556183) suite aux choix de plusieurs ministres du gouvernement Jospin d'utiliser le féminin. Les conclusions du [rapport](https://www.apfa.asso.fr/apfa/feminis2.pdf) qui a suivi sont très prudentes mais ne ferment pas la porte à *la ministre* en recommandant de s'en tenir à l'usage.

Voici par exemple un texte officiel ayant plus de vingt ans utilisant le féminin :

[Arrêté du 19 février 1998 relatif à l'attribution par **la ministre** de la culture et de la communication de bourses d'études chorégraphiques](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000555116&categorieLien=id).

Les choix étant souvent plus idéologiques que linguistiques (comme les votes négatifs à ma réponse...), les ministres peuvent choisir elles-mêmes que le féminin soit utilisé ou non pour ce qui les concerne. La dernière femme ministre opposante notable à la féminisation de son titre est Michèle Alliot-Marie, ministre de 1993 à 2011.

Pour *médecin*, on évite l'homonyme *médecine* et l'usage est soit de garder le masculin (neutre) *un médecin* ou, comme déjà suggéré en 1986, d'utiliser un article au féminin (**une médecin**).

Ce problème ne se pose pas pour une dentiste, une pédiatre, une généraliste, une anesthésiste, une chirurgienne, etc.

Dans d'autres pays francophones comme le Canada, La Suisse ou la Belgique, l'utilisation du féminin n'a pas provoqué autant de controverses qu'en France. 
Par exemple dès 1976, [Lise Payette](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lise_Payette), ministre à la condition féminine, à la consommation, aux coopératives et institutions financières du gouvernement René Levesque se fait appeler *la ministre*. En 1979, la Gazette officielle du Québec a recommandé l'utilisation de *la ministre*, *la directrice*, *la secrétaire*, etc.

En Suisse, le  Dictionnaire suisse romand indique que la plus ancienne attestation de *ministre* utilisé au féminin est présente dans L’Illustré daté du 25 novembre 1948.

Comment: Je ne sais pas pourquoi, mais y'a que "une médecine" qui choque... Peut être parce que "médecine" fait déjà référence à la discipline, et qu'on est trop habitué à entendre "**la** médecine", et non "**une** médecine". On peut d'ailleur faire référence à la série "Docteur Quinn, femme médecin", qui ajoute "femme" plutôt que de mettre un "e" à médecin...

Comment: @Random Au XVIIème, l'Académie française aurait supprimé le féminin de plusieurs professions jugées trop savantes ou ne convenant pas à une femme (autrice, écrivaine, médecine, jugesse, peintresse, philosophesse, jugesse, ...). Intéressant de savoir toutefois qu'ils ont existé (en supposant que ma source est fiable, ce que je n'ai pas eu le temps de vérifier).

Comment: @Chop "ecrivaine" ne me choque pas ! Les autres par contre, c'est intéressant en effet... !

Comment: @Chop : Je peux confirmer la disparition au XVIIe de ces formes féminines mais... pas la responsabilité de cette disparition ;) (cf ma contribution)

Answer (score 11):

Juste pour partiellement confirmer une observation de @chop en commentaires :

Le [*Dictionnaire du Moyen Français*](http://www.atilf.fr/dmf/) (~1330-~1500) atteste effectivement un certain nombre de formes féminines :

- jugesse (ou jugeresse)
- autrice
- e**s**crivaine
- peintresse (peint**e**resse dans le *Godfroy*)
- philosophesse
- medecine

Le XVIIe est effectivement celui de la fixation du français avec, coïncidemment la publication du *Dictionnaire* mais je ne crois pas pour autant l'Académie responsable de l'éviction des formes féminines et encore moins la raison donnée dans le commentaire.

Le débat sur la forme féminine de ces mots s'est engagé avec, au premier chef, *poétesse* qui, d'après le DHLF, parce qu'il avait pris un sens péjoratif, est sorti d'usage au profit d'*un**e** poète*.

C'est en réalité Boisregard et surtout Ménage (refusé à l'AF) qui avaient fait... le ménage bien avant en condamnant *philosophesse, propriétairesse, dépositairesse, peinteresse, medecine, autrice, jugesse, oratrice*... au point qu'ils étaient sortis d'usage. ET on notera que le *Dictionnaire* conserve *avocate, conseillère, traductrice, rhétoricienne*...

On lira sur le sujet avec intérêt l'[étude savante d'Anne Debrosse](https://www.persee.fr/doc/rhren_1771-1347_2014_num_78_1_3361).

Answer (score 4):

En complément, voici le texte de l'[avis](http://numerique.banq.qc.ca/patrimoine/details/52327/2360633) de l'Office québécois de la langue française ([OQLF](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)) du 28 juillet 1979 (à la p. 7394) [publié](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazette_officielle_du_Qu%C3%A9bec) conformément aux [dispositions](http://www.legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/showdoc/cs/C-11#se:116) de la *Charte de la langue française*, auquel on réfère souvent, comme en témoigne une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17905) :

> **Avis de recommandation**
>
> Conformément à l'article 116 de la Charte de la langue
>   française, avis public est donné que l'Office de la langue
>   française, à sa séance régulière du 6 juillet 1979, a recommandé:
>
> *Féminisation des titres*
>
> Relativement au genre des appellations d'emploi, l'utilisation des
>   formes féminines dans tous les cas possibles:
>   — soit à l'aide du
>   féminin  usité.  Exemples: couturière, infirmière, avocate;
>   —
>   soit à l'aide du terme épicène marqué par un déterminant féminin.
>   Exemples:  une journaliste, une architecte, une ministre;
>  — soit
>   par la création spontanée d'une forme féminine qui respecte la
>   morphologie française. Exemples: députée, chirurgienne,
>   praticienne;
>   — soit par l'adjonction du mot femme. Exemples:
>   femme-magistrat, femme-chef d'entreprise, femme-ingénieur.

Answer (score 3):

C'est en grande discussion à l'Assemblée, voir :

http://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2014/01/24/feminisation-des-titres_n_4657019.html
http://www.ouest-france.fr/monde/femmes-faut-il-dire-madame-le-ministre-ou-madame-la-ministre-3233803

bien que l'Académie soutienne la forme « Madame **le** Ministre », voir :

http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-maire

Answer (score -1):

En effet il s'agit d'une hérésie : non pas que le mot soit masculin mais bien neutre. Or en français, il n'existe pas de genre neutre comme en allemand ou en latin. Si bien que c'est le masculin qui est utilisé pour exprimer, par exemple, la neutralité d'une fonction.

Ainsi, que ce soit un homme ou une femme, le ministre est toujours le ministre. Si on veut faire la distinction, on dit alors "Madame le ministre".

Tout autre forme est, d'une part, une erreur d'accord entre la fonction et la personne (cf. Académie française) et d'autre part une simple intention d'inclure à tort dans la langue un programme politique.

Comment: Admettons que ministre serait une fonction. Mais que penser alors de [«chancelière»](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_Merkel)?

Comment: C'est la femme du chancelier.

Comment: Ce sera plutôt le chancelier qui sera le mari de la chancelière dans ce cas, je suppose...