# How do words that are of one gender change when they refer to something of the opposite gender?

Tags: accord

I am learning French so go easy on me.

I know that some words change when they refer to feminine than masculine. So I say "mon amie" when referring to a girl and "mon ami" when referring to a guy.
But what about words like "groupe" or "professeur" that are always masculine? If I have a female professor, can I say "cette professeur"? What about a band that has all female members, can I say "cette groupe"?

What if the sentence contains "groupe de musique", can I use "cette"? My assumption is that because the word musique is feminine, it also affects the word groupe, but I can be wrong.

If my question or explanation is confused, can you please help me get it straight? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's a common misconception that grammatical gender corresponds to real-world gender. This is not really the case. Every boy is *une personne* (f). Every girl is *un ange* (m).

That said, for whatever reason, certain words for human beings and animals *do* have alternative forms according to real-world gender. These are called *épicène*. Some of them don't change form (*un enfant*, *une enfant*). Some of them do (*un enseignant*, *une enseignante*).

The words in this group are mostly professions and epithets. In modern times, as more professions have become open to any gender, there has been a corresponding push to make its word *épicène*. Sometimes [this meets backlash from purists](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17900/est-ce-une-h%C3%A9r%C3%A9sie-de-dire-madame-la-ministre).

Popular usage always beats purism in the end when it comes to language, but it does sometimes leave us without an "authority" to dictate the "correct" form. For example, with *professeur*, is the feminine *professeur*, *professeure*, or *professeuse* ?

In such cases you can [consult Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la%20professeur%2C%20la%20professeure%2C%20la%20professeuse&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) or other corpora to see what most people choose and follow that. Or you can hedge your bets, follow what authoritative articles tell you ("ministre is always masculine!") and as a learner people will usually understand you and not give you a hard time.

---

The second question is easier to answer: a genitive *never* changes the gender of the main word, i.e. the head. *Un groupe de musique* is masculine. *Une troupe de soldats* is feminine.

Comment: Making words epicene didn't just happen in modern times. I suspected (from its use in some French poetry that I've read) that *enfant* was always masculine in the early 19th century.  This is confirmed by [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+enfant%2C+une+enfant+&year_start=1750&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 0):

`What if the sentence contains "groupe de musique", can I use "cette"? My assumption is that because the word musique is feminine, it also affects the word groupe, but I can be wrong.`

No, you have to use `ce`, because the subject is not `musique` but `groupe`, no matter the `musique` gender.

`But what about words like "groupe" or "professeur" that are always masculine? If I have a female professor, can I say "cette professeur"?`

Well. It's a bit complicated.
You can say `la professeure` or `la professeur`.
Here is a useful resource.
The subject is a little too big to be summarized here I think:

https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/culture-generale/a-trancher-bonne-toutes-feminisation-noms-de-metiers/

Comment: Thank you. Can't choose both as answer but this was equally helpful.